# javascript setInterval - countdown lagging

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdown

I use this code below for a countdown in seconds. The problem is that when the part of the page including the countdown is loaded again using jquery .load, the new countdown becomes wrong : at every second, we see fast 2 seconds, like this : 9-8...7-6...5-4... as if it was not synchronised with the clock...  See it there : aorbaroquethrash.com/test (for the problem to happen, I have to change song while you're there)

Any idea how I can solve this?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
/*author Philip M. 2010*/

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs)-1;
ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);   // every second
}

function tick() {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs>0) {
timeInSecs--;
}
else {
clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
}

document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = secs;
} 
startTimer(<?php echo $stream['info']['length'];?>);

</script>
```

Patrick

Comment: Any chance the script is present twice?

Comment: Okay... network is set to log everything, my sound card is muted, now let's just wait for three minutes.

Comment: Just as expected... after each change, the clock starts ticking faster and faster.

Comment: What about the referenceError that happens when you change the song that causes you not to clear your timer? Have you actually tried debugging?

Comment: Jan, how do you see this referenceError?   Maybe I should do 'clearInterval' when there's a new song, but I don't know how yet.

Comment: You already attempt `clearInterval` but you don't seem to succeed. I guess that's caused by the referenceError. To see it, open the javascript console and change the song.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the current system time to display or calculate how many seconds have elapsed rather than doing your own count.  `setInterval()` is not guaranteed to be called perfectly on time and you can potentially get accumulating error when you just count yourself and you will display the wrong time if it isn't called on time.

Record the time that you start countingand then on each tick, get the new system time and calculate how much time has elapsed since you started counting with no accumulating error.

---

Also, please don't pass strings to `setInterval()`. Pass a real function reference as this prevents scoping issues and other potential problems.

---

Here's an example of working code for a countdown timer:

```
var startTime, countAmt, interval;

function now() {
  return ((new Date()).getTime());
}

function tick() {
  var elapsed = now() - startTime;
  var cnt = countAmt - elapsed;
  var elem = document.getElementById("counter");
  if (cnt > 0) {
    elem.innerHTML = Math.round(cnt / 1000);
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = "0";
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

function startTimer(secs) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = secs;
  countAmt = secs * 1000;
  startTime = now();
  interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);  
}

startTimer(20);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mxntj/

Comment: `setInterval` can't drift actually (but it can skip, if the CPU is highly loaded - which is worse)

Comment: @JanDvorak - but if it isn't called on time or an interval call is skipped, then the OP's code will display the wrong time elapsed.

Comment: OK. So what should be done then?

Comment: @trogne - I thought explained it.  Use `new Date().getTime()` (the system time) when you start measuring time, store it in a variable as your start time and then use `new Date().getTime()` again on each timer call to calculate how much time has elapsed since your start time.  This be much more be accurate.

Comment: @trogne - I put a working example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all.

I needed to do add 'clearInterval(ticker);' at the beginning of function startTimer.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for, I know this is 10 years later, but this is still valid, it's a cleanup issue that's causing the lag!
BTW, I'm using the setInterval in react, in a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1):

I've added this to the jfriend00 script to get 'minutes:secs' :

```
function minute(secs){
    minVar = Math.floor(secs/60);
    secs = secs % 60;
    if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0"+secs;
    }
    return minVar+":"+secs;
}
```

Added to : 
    elem.innerHTML = minute(Math.round(cnt / 1000));
and
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = minute(secs);