# Inefficient javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I have created a very simple countdown timer in js which every element of time is calculated out. It works, the only issue with it is there exists lag most likely caused from the calculations being made every second. Any thoughts as to how to make this more efficient?

js:

```
var count = 55010; //needs to be in seconds
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
function timer(){
  count = count-1;
  if (count <= -1){
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("hour10").innerHTML=Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*2.4);
  document.getElementById("hour1").innerHTML=Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*24)-(Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*2.4))*10;
  document.getElementById("min10").innerHTML=Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*6);
  document.getElementById("min1").innerHTML = Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*60)-(Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*6))*10;
  document.getElementById("sec10").innerHTML = Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*6);
  document.getElementById("sec1").innerHTML = Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*60)-(Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*6))*10;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="hour10">0</span>
<span id="hour1">0</span> :
<span id="min10">0</span>
<span id="min1">0</span> :
<span id="sec10">0</span>
<span id="sec1">0</span>
```

The reason I have created the timer in this fashion is because I want to put each element into a div container like so:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lag is from your browser not being very careful about how accurately it keeps track of time. Your calculations take almost no time at all.

Comment: The reason for the lag is not the use of inefficient calculations, but the drifting `setInterval`. Just change it to use an [accurate time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript setInterval - countdown lagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186771/javascript-setinterval-countdown-lagging)

Answer (score 0):

A way to make this more efficient is to keep a reference to the elements by only searching the Dom once, and also use innerText if you are not using any markup

```
var count = 55010; //needs to be in seconds
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
var elHour10 = document.getElementById("hour10");
var elHour1 = document.getElementById("hour1");
var elMin1 = document.getElementById("min10");
var elSec10 = document.getElementById("sec10");
var elSec1 = document.getElementById("sec1");

function timer(){
  count = count-1;
  if (count <= -1){
    clearInterval(counter);

    return;
  }
  elHour10.innerText=Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*2.4);
  elHour1.innerText=Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*24)-(Math.floor(((count/86400)%1)*2.4))*10;
  elMin10.innerText=Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*6);
  elMin1.innerText = Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*60)-(Math.floor(((count/3600)%1)*6))*10;
  elSec10.innerText = Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*6);
  elSec1.innerText = Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*60)-(Math.floor(((count/60)%1)*6))*10;
}
```